# Sending e-mail using CDO in EXCEL vba TSL not SSL

Tags: excel, email, ssl, cdo.message, vba

I try to send e-mails using the CDO of Excel VBA. The SMTP server I use require that I send the message with **TSL** encryption and not SSL. (I've tested it with email sent from an ordinary mailprogram changing between SSL and TLS). When sending a message using the

```
...
set mail  = CDO_Config.Fields    
mail.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True
...
```

I get 'the transport could not connect to the server' (I've translated it from danish).

All parameters ARE correct concerning the fields. I've tested with other STMP-servers NOT using TSL-encryption, sending mail without problems. Therefore I don't include these lines.

Fields used: *sendusing, smtpserver, smtpserverport, smtpauthenticate, smtpusessl, 
sendusername, sendpassword, smtpconnectiontimeout*.

Is it possible to send using the TSL encryption? I've found nothing on the net (10+ hours of research)

Thank you.

Comment: Im trying to install the TSL update for window, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3140245

Comment: Did it work for you? It looks as THE solution.

Comment: it did not work, I believe we need to use the reference of library, but cant find it yet

Comment: Damn,  that it wasn't. I'm attentive towards your experimentations ...